# Divide Numpy array by constant to make hours days

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Hello so I have created the following plot from some data extracted from a netCDF file. [Plot created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfuZA.png) . I used the following script:

```
# import netCDF

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import netCDF4
from pylab import rcParams

f = netCDF4.Dataset('data', 'r')
v = f.variables['store_Bio'][0:27, 0:23, 0]


# Reshape array
r = np.reshape(v, 621)

# plot asthetics
plt.plot(r, linestyle='-', linewidth=5.0, c='c')
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Average Biogenic Emissions (kg/hour/per cell area)')
plt.title('Average Biogenic Emissions March 2013')
plt.ylim(0, 350)
plt.xlim(0, 621)

# Annotate plot
plt.annotate('Daytime Maximum', xy=(72, 140), xytext=(24, 200),
             arrowprops=dict(facecolor='black', shrink=0.05,
                             width=0.1, headwidth=10))

# change plot size
rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 25, 5

# change ticks
plt.xticks(range(0, 621, 12), [str(i) for i in range(0, 621, 12)])
plt.yticks(range(0, 350, 50), [str(i) for i in range(0, 350, 50)])

plt.show()
```

However, I was wondering how I could divide only the dates by 24 so that the x-axis displays days instead of hours and everything else remains the same. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I guess the dates are in the first column of `r`, so `date = r[:,0]/24.`, and `plot(date, r[:,1])`.

Comment: Hey thanks for the comment! I tried this and get the error 'Too many indices for array'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your data `r` is 1D it doesn't have any timestamps, so the x-axis is just the running index of your array. If you want date information you either need to read it from the CDF file, or create a time axis yourself:

```
# Reshape array
r = np.reshape(v, 621)
date = np.arange(r.shape[0])  # assume that delta time between data is 1 hour
date1 = date/24.  # use days instead of hours


# plot asthetics
plt.plot(date1, r, linestyle='-', linewidth=5.0, c='c')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the **vectorization** concept

```
import numpy as np

In [31]: a=np.arange(0,621,12)

In [32]: a/24.0
Out[32]: 
array([  0. ,   0.5,   1. ,   1.5,   2. ,   2.5,   3. ,   3.5,   4. ,
         4.5,   5. ,   5.5,   6. ,   6.5,   7. ,   7.5,   8. ,   8.5,
         9. ,   9.5,  10. ,  10.5,  11. ,  11.5,  12. ,  12.5,  13. ,
        13.5,  14. ,  14.5,  15. ,  15.5,  16. ,  16.5,  17. ,  17.5,
        18. ,  18.5,  19. ,  19.5,  20. ,  20.5,  21. ,  21.5,  22. ,
        22.5,  23. ,  23.5,  24. ,  24.5,  25. ,  25.5])
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, however how do I use my array into the above coding?

Comment: @MatMoon Are you referring to `r = np.reshape(v, 621)` this array?

Comment: yep that's the one I'm talking about :) Because when I try your method it just plots a line with a slight incline

Comment: @MatMoon then `w=r/24.0` should do the trick and use `w` instead of `r`

Comment: this divides everything in the array by 24 which isn't really what I'm going for

Comment: I think this is because the array has been reshaped and hence is only a string of numbers. I think If I added a column which I can divide by 24 it could work.